# OpenLayers and specific symbol

Tags: openlayers-2, symbology

I'm trying to use a specific marker with my GeoJSON files. They don't show up despite my readings and Firebug.

Can anyone help ?

```
var map = new OpenLayers.Map('map');    
var emprise_style = new OpenLayers.Symbolizer.Point({
    externalGraphic: '../symbol/marker.png'
    });

var empriseStyleMap = new OpenLayers.StyleMap({'default': emprise_style});
var emprise_layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("GeoJSON", {
        projection: "EPSG:3857",
        strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()],
        protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
            url: "emprise.geojson",
            format: new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON()
            }),
        styleMap: empriseStyleMap
    });
map.addLayer(emprise_layer)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try Style instead of Symbolizer

```
var emprise_style = new OpenLayers.Style({
        externalGraphic:"${symbol}"
    },{
    context:{
          symbol:function(feature){

         /*
           with this u can use different symbols for different data values in the "feature" e.g. 
           if feature has property school and hospital

          if (feature.property == 'school') 
          {
              return '../symbol/school_marker'; 
           }
          else if (feature.property == 'hospital'){
                return '../symbol/hospital_marker';
          }
          */


          return '../symbol/marker.png';
       }    
    }
    });
```

Comment: thx.i m a beginner in openlayers and i d like to learn step by step. Your answer is a bit too complicated for now. I only want a unique symbol..and that s already a challenge for me !

Comment: if you want unique symbol you can directly use `externalGraphic:'../symbol/marker.png'` and remove the context part....